# Why is a miracle happening on this double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to solve a double integral of the form

$$\int_0^\infty du\int_0^\infty dx \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^{2n+1}f\left(\sqrt{x^2+u}\right),$$

where $f$ is a well-behaved **even** function that decays rapidly at infinity. The content of this question (and miracle) does not depend on the specific $f$, as long as it is even and well behaved, but $f(t)=e^{-t^2}$ is a fine example. Note that since $1/x$ multiplies an odd function, the integrand is nonsingular as $x\to0$.

**I would like to have a solution for a generic integer $n$, in terms of the known quantities $f^{(m)}(0)$ (i.e., arbitrary $m$th derivatives of $f$ evaluated at zero).**

Amazingly, such a solution seems to always exist (I have tested up to $n = 5$), but the method I am using is extremely tedious, relies on Mathematica, and results in infinite terms that miraculously cancel. So the question is, what's a more efficient and clear method to get the same result?

---

Step 1: Evaluate all $2n+1$ derivatives.

Step 2: Transform the first integral with the change of variables $u=y^2,du=2ydy$.

Step 3: Convert to polar coordinates.

Step 4: Evaluate the $\theta$-integral.

Step 5: What remains is an integral of the form $\int_0^\infty dr\left(c_1\frac{1}{r^{p_1}}f^{(q_1)}(r) + \cdots + c_r r^{p_N}f^{(q_N)}(r)\right)$. Some of the terms with powers of $x$ in the denominator are infinite, but integrating by parts on some terms always makes these cancel. The terms with positive powers of $x$ can be integrated by parts repeatedly until they become $\int_0^\infty dr f^{(m)}(r) = - f^{(m-1)}(0)$.

---

Steps 1–4 can be performed by Mathematica using the single line (here $n=2$):

```
Integrate[
 Assuming[{r, \[Theta]} \[Element] PositiveReals, 
  2r Tan[\[Theta]] D[f[Sqrt[x^2 + u]], {x, 2*2 + 1}] /. {x -> 
      r Cos[\[Theta]], u -> r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2} // 
   Simplify], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}]
```

I invite you to copy/paste this line in, examine the output and verify what I have claimed in step 5. It may seem pointless for me to ask this question, given that I already have a method for getting to a solution; however, Mathematica starts taking a very long time to compute this even for $n=5$, and even still the above line does not consider the final integrations by parts that make several more terms vanish and combine, so I think a better method is needed for both efficiency and understanding's sake.

Comment: In your Mathematica formula, you seem to have not included the $\frac{1}{x}$ factor. After Step 3, you should end up with $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathrm{d}\theta \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r \, (2 r \tan\theta)\frac{\partial^{2n+1}}{\partial x^{2n+1}} f(r), $$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks, that was indeed a mistake. It seems that my comments about step 5 remain true after correcting this—the miracle still occurs.

Comment: @SangchulLee I just took another look and realized my previous comment is wrong. After correcting to $2r\tan\theta$, my method gives the same final answer as your method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I$ denote the integral. Then by the Fubini's theorem and Leibniz's integral rule,

\begin{align*}
I 
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \, \frac{1}{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2n+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2n+1}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}u \, f(\sqrt{x^2+u}) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \, \frac{1}{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2n+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2n+1}} \int_{x}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}s \, 2s f(s) \tag{$s=\sqrt{x^2+u}$} \\
&= -2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \, \frac{1}{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2n}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2n}} x f(x) \\
&= -2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \, \frac{1}{x} \bigl( x f^{(2n)}(x) + 2n f^{(2n-1)}(x) \bigr) \\
&= - 4n \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \, \frac{f^{(2n-1)}(x)}{x}
\end{align*}

In the fourth step, we utilized the [general Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), and in the last step $f^{(2n-1)}(0) = 0$ is used. Given this formula, I see no reason for this to reduce to a linear combination of $f^{(k)}(0)$'s. For instance,

- If $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ and $n = 2$, then $I = -32\sqrt{\pi}$.
- If $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $n = 2$, then $I = -24\pi$.
- If $f(x) = \operatorname{sech} x$ and $n = 2$, then $I = 8\pi - \frac{1}{\pi^3}\psi^{(3)}\bigl(\tfrac{1}{4}\bigr) $, where $\psi^{(m)}$ is the polygamma function of order $m$.

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach for practical purposes. However, I still feel like there's a miracle hiding here because the method I outlined always seems to give an answer in terms of $f^{(k)}(0)$'s. In my case, my $f$ is ugly, and Mathematica cannot find an analytical solution to $\int_0^\infty dx f^{(2n-1)}(x)/x$. So my method suggests there exists a "closed-form" solution, whereas this method requires numerical integration (in my case).

Comment: I may end up implementing this method, so again thank you for this approach. I'm just still curious about whether a solution in terms of $f^{(m)}(0)$'s also exists.

Comment: I just took another look and realized that, after making the correction to my method that you pointed out in the comments, my method gives the same final integral as yours. Before I thought that my answer was giving the same result in a simpler form, but that's not true.